# Facebook Login verify access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have implemented facebook login and the flow is like below:

- The user clicks on Fb login button
- I call the **FB.login** button
- Once i get the response.status as connected i call the **/me** api to
  get user details And the done some other stuff

My Point is do i need to validate the **access token** somewhere in between these steps.

This is how i initialize

```
FB.init({
                appId: 'app_id',
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true,
                version: 'v2.4'
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don´t need to verify the token between these steps, you should just handle errors in the callback of `FB.api`. Also, you can refresh the token for returning users with [`FB.getLoginStatus`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus), but you should use it on page load only.

Here is a tutorial, if you need more information: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/